# JavaScript string doesn't get displayed on the page

Tags: javascript

pretty new to javascript and doing some examples from a book, can't understand why this isn't producing any text strings on the page when loaded.

```
function init()
{
var sum = 80 + 20;
var sub = sum - 50;
var mul = sum * 5;
var div = sum / 4;
var mod = sum % 2;
var inc = ++sum;
var dec = --sum;

var str = "Sum: " + sum;
str += "<br>Subtraction: " + sub;
str += "<br>Multiplication: " + mul;
str += "<br>Division: " + div;
str += "<br>Modulus: " + mod;
str += "<br>Increment: " + inc;
str += "<br>Decrement: " + dec;

document.getElementById( "Panel" ).innerHTML = str;
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded" , init , false);
```

And the html5 code;

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="arithmetic.js"></script>
<title>Doing Arithmetic</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="panel"> </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Panel in your Javascript code should probably be in lowercase so it matches :)

Comment: wow. what an idiot. i have read over every letter for the last half an hour, didn't notice that though! Thanks very much everyone!

Comment: Personally I would change the HTML to match the JS id. No-one likes capitalised html attributes. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `<div>` has an `id` of `panel`, not `Panel`. The IDs need to match. So you can either change the JavaScript code:

```
document.getElementById( "panel" )
```

or the HTML:

```
<div id="Panel"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<div id="panel"> </div>
```

with

```
<div id="Panel"> </div>
```

and it will work. P in panel should be capital.